# Entity framework code first approach - one to one relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My model association is (as i believe) one-to-one:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("BlockedAccount")]
    public virtual Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual BlockedAccount BlockedAccount { get; set; }
}

public class BlockedAccount
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid BlockedAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BanLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BannedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Reason { get; set; }
}
```

But when I am trying to use it, the program crashes and it gives me following exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.BlockedAccounts_AccountId". The conflict occurred
>   in database "Accounts", table "dbo.BlockedAccounts", column
>   'BlockedAccountId'. The statement has been terminated.

What am i doing wrong here? I want `AccountId` to point at `BlockedAccountId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you attaching your entities?  You don't need to actually set the foreign key, simply attaching to the navigation properties will make the connection.  This code, with your model above works for me:

```
     public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("BlockedAccount")]
    public virtual Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual BlockedAccount BlockedAccount { get; set; }
}

public class BlockedAccount
{
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid BlockedAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BanLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BannedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Reason { get; set; }

    public BlockedAccount()
    {
        BannedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class Model : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlockedAccount> BlockedAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new BlockedAccount()
            {
               BlockedAccountId = Guid.NewGuid()
            };
        var a = new Account();

        a.BlockedAccount = b;
        Model m = new Model();
        m.Accounts.Add(a);
        m.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Heh, I thought that there must be something wrong with my ef... I am executing your code with my model, and still i get error posted in first post... So now I am definitely stuck... You maybe know how to reinstall EF?

Comment: I've updated the answer with my entire app - does yours still error? Are you running the most current version of EF (5.0) if not, you can update using [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework): install-package entityframework

Comment: Ok. So it's pretty weird, when i adjusted my code so it match yours, i still had errors, but when i copy-pasted it and isolated from rest of my model, the magic happened and everything worked. So i no have a starting point in debugging my model. Thank you, that helped me. :-)